Snowflake Transpose table, how do I achieve this?
So in Snowflake I have data as shown in the left and I wanna transform the data as shown on the right.
How do I achieve this?
Input :
user_id  column_name  value
1        Name         John
1        Age          25
1        City         New York
2        Name         Alice
2        Age          30
2        City         LA

Output :
user_id  Name  Age City
1        John  25  New York
2        Alice 30  LA

I tried asking chat gpt but didnt help too much! I was hoping anyone here has a clear answer, need to have SQL query as efficient as possible!

Please don't link to images. Add all relevant information to your question as editable text, appropriately formatted (code as code, data as tables). The main reason for this is so that someone can copy your data if they want to try out a solution

One option could be PIVOT.
Select  user_id, name, age, city
From    ( Select * 
          From tbl 
          PIVOT ( Max(val) 
                  For column_name IN('Name' name, 'Age' age, 'City' city) ) 
        )


Thanks I didnt realise I had to use MAX. This works!
